# Is it possible to intercept taking screenshot event when my app is in the foreground

Tags: android, screenshot

Is it possible to intercept taking screenshot event (or create a listener for it) when my app is in the foreground? I want to execute some own code when a screenshot is taken by vol down+power key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, you do not get control on a screenshot. If your objective is to prevent your app from having a screenshot taken (e.g., security reasons), use `FLAG_SECURE`:

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oki, i was hoping to get the screenshot that was taken and use it within my app..

Comment: @Luizje: I do not believe that there is a guaranteed location of where the screenshot will be stored. That's not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Thnx, i think i can make it work by adding FileObserver to listen to CREATE events, and than retrieve the screenshot when the event is triggered..

Comment: @Luizje: `FileObserver` requires a specific directory. I do not believe that there is a guaranteed location of where the screenshot will be stored. That's not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: That won't be a problem because my app will be only used on one type of device.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this task is to add a file observer on the screenshot directory. Writing sample code below to observe the file path
**The screenshot file observer**
    package com.example.main;

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenshotObserver extends FileObserver {
        private static final String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/Screenshots";
        private static final String TAG = "ScreenshotObserver";

        private ScreenshotListener listener;
        private String mLastTakenPath;

        ScreenshotObserver(ScreenshotListener listener) {
            super(PATH);
            this.listener = listener;
            Log.d(TAG, PATH);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Detected new file added %s", path));
            if (path==null || event != FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE)
                Log.d(TAG, "Don't care.");
            else if (mLastTakenPath!=null && path.equalsIgnoreCase(mLastTakenPath))
                Log.d(TAG, "This event has been observed before.");
            else {
                mLastTakenPath = path;
                listener.onScreenshotTaken(path);
                Log.d(TAG, "Send event to listener.");
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            super.startWatching();
            Log.d(TAG, "Start Watching.");
        }

        public void stop() {
            super.stopWatching();
            Log.d(TAG, "Stop Watching.");
        }
}
```

**Activity that implement the file observer**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ScreenshotListener{
    private ScreenshotObserver obs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        obs = new ScreenshotObserver(this);
        obs.start();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenshotTaken( String path ) {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.monText);
        t.setText("Screenshot taken ! " + path);
    }
}
```

Comment: The screenshot directory is not part of Android's public API, which means it can differ per device. If you opt for a solution like this, the only viable option you have is to create a map from device to screenshot directory.  All in all I wouldn't recommend going down that road.

Comment: Could you please post an example with description.